# How to export source timecode and clip names as an overlay in Premiere?

Tags: premiere, adobe, export, timecode

I need to supply timecode, source timecode, and source filenames as an overlay for a colour grade.
In Premiere, I have set up my Overlay settings as shown:
[image: overlay]

Note the checked box "enable overlays for transmit"
But when I export as usual I do not see the overlays.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This https://premierebro.com/blog/an-overview-of-overlays-in-premiere-pro suggests it's not possible... But a grader has asked for it...

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found out the answer. It is possible, but fiddly.

For the source timecodes for every clip:

1. Duplicate your sequence.
2. Find the Timecode effects in the Effects panel and apply it to the first clip in the sequence.
3. Double click the clip and go to Effects controls and make sure the Timecode Source effect is set to "Media".
4. Then copy the first clip on the timeline.
5. Select all video clips on the timeline and then Paste Attributes, just the Timecode is needed, untick everything else.

You will now see all the clips have the original source timecode and this can be compared to the original master clip.

To show the filenames of every clip on a given track:

1. Add a transparent video layer.
2. Add it to the timeline.
3. Add the Clip Name effect to it.
4. Double click on the transparent video clip and go to Effects controls and select under File Name - Display choose - FileName
   and under Source track choose the track that the clips are on on the timeline.
5. You may need to move this down a bit to avoid overlapping the timecode.

If you need to add filenames from another video track, just copy the Clip Name effect on your transparent video layer, and paste it below the existing effect, then adjust the position and size of each effect.

Answer (score 0):

Even easier, apply BOTH the timecode effect AND the Clip Name effect to the transparent clip and assign V1 or whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Here was my workaround:

Apply a timecode effect to first video clip. This allows you to set multiple overlays (source and record timecode as well file name).

Position everything where you want it - and then copy the effect to all other clips in your sequence.

Ideally works best if you've collapsed all video to 1 track beforehand.